# How to #define the device height as Macro in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to define `SCREEN_HEIGHT` in my app. I used the following code, but it always return 568 for me.Can anyone help me for this?

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

#ifdef IS_IPHONE_5
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 568
#else
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480
#endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: see my edited answer. it is working in my code also my friend...

Comment: @PanktiPatel Obviously the `#DEFINE` is a compile-time exercise, but the screen height is a run-time determination. So your `#DEFINE` of `SCREEN_HEIGHT` cannot use a constant, but rather must represent some run-time expression (such as something that looks at `[UIScreen mainScreen]` properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #define height  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i want screen height. I just need to define it as in #if and #endif statement.

Answer (score 2):

Write this below line in prifix.pch file...

```
#define    SCREEN_HEIGHT   [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

this will definetly work..i tried it in my code....

Hope it will help my friend...

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i don't want to use any variable for this. I just need to define it as in #if and #endif statement.

Comment: @PanktiPatel - without apply condition how can use properly `if` statement ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `#undef SCREEN_HEIGHT` before `#define SCREEN_HEIGHT`

```
#undef SCREEN_HEIGHT
#ifdef IS_IPHONE_5
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 568
#else
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Define Screen Height as:

```
#define ScreenBound       ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds])
#define ScreenHeight      (ScreenBound.size.height)
```